# How do you configure the EBS block size to be different than the default?

Tags: amazon-web-services, block-storage

The AWS documentation here says that the default block size is 4 KiB: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/volume_constraints.html#block_size

It says that 8 KiB, 16 KiB, 32 KiB, and 64 KiB are also supported... but I don't see anything in the documentation that says how to change it from the default, and I don't see any fields in the [BlockDeviceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-launchtemplate-blockdevicemapping-ebs.html#cfn-ec2-launchtemplate-blockdevicemapping-ebs-volumetype) that allow you to configure this.

Is there some way to configure this?

Comment: I _think_ that configuration is controlled inside the OS. Similar to managing logical volumes. So, if you're attaching this to an EC2 instance, you might consider doing this in the user scripts.

Comment: Ok... so normally with linux you can change the disk block size by using the `blockdev --setbsz` command, but that requires the device to be unmounted when you change it.  Can you even do that with an EBS volume?  I thought you couldn't unmount/mount EBS volumes on a running instance?

Comment: That documentation you linked specifically says: "non-default block sizes that can be specified during formatting"

Comment: Ok... but how?  Can someone give an example?

Comment: How are you creating the EC2 instance?

Comment: EC2 AutoScaling group